# Is there an equivalent to "sealed" or "final" in TypeScript?

Tags: inheritance, typescript, final, typescript2.0, sealed

I'm trying to implement a method in a super class that should be available for use, but not changeable, in sub classes.  Consider this:

```
export abstract class BaseClass {
    universalBehavior(): void {
        doStuff(); // Do some universal stuff the same way in all sub classes
        specializedBehavior(); // Delegate specialized stuff to sub classes
    }

    protected abstract specializedBehavior(): void;
}
```

My intention would be that any sub class of BaseClass would not only be free to omit implementation of `universalBehavior()`, but not even be allowed to provide an implementation.  Is this not (yet) possible in TypeScript?  Intellisense complains when I omit the implementation in my sub classes.  The best I can seem to do is this:

```
export class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    universalBehavior(): void {
        super.universalBehavior();
    }

    specializedBehavior(): void {
        // sub class' implementation
    }
}
```

Obviously this is problematic because I have to ensure that no sub class ever implements `universalBehavior()` with anything other than a call to `super.universalBehavior()`.

Comment: Here's the discussion on adding `final` to TypeScript: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8306

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - So I guess there is no keyword.  Perhaps someone will post a workaround of some sort.

Comment: I've seen the use of [a `@readonly` decorator](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2015/10/20/typescript-decorators/), which will use [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) on the object, but that's not the same thing (it disallows any modification to the class).

Comment: In JavaScript this problem usually solved by invoking prototype method directly on any subclass, instead of making use of prototype chain. One example that is often can be seen `Object.hasOwnProperty.call(target, "some-property")` to check if property comes from object itself and not from prototype chain. You can use the same trick and it won't even matter if subclass shadows this method or not.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No, at the time of this writing there is not.  There is a proposal for such a keyword which is still being considered, but may or may not ever be implemented.

See:

- [github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9264](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9264), and
- [github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8306](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8306)

Answer (score 34):

Example of implementation hack of 'sealed method' as readonly property of type function which throws compiler error when attempting to override in extended class:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    protected element: JQuery<HTMLElement>;
    constructor(element: JQuery<HTMLElement>) {
        this.element = element;
    }
    readonly public dispose = (): void => {
        this.element.remove();
    }
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    constructor(element: JQuery<HTMLElement>) {
        super(element);
    }
    public dispose(): void { } // Compiler error: "Property 'dispose' in type 'MyClass' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'BaseClass'"
}
```

---

TypeScript 2.0 supports "final" classes through using of private constructor:

```
class A {
    private constructor(){}
}

class B extends A{} //Cannot extend a class 'A'. Class constructor is marked as private.ts(2675)
```

Comment: Nice catch! Not even sure this is a hack. Looks perfectly valid and expected to me.

Comment: Although, I fail to see the logic of throwing error here, since extending base prototype in JavaScript this way doesn't modify it at all.

Comment: @weaknespase I think how the compiler converts the Typescript to Javascript has changed, because putting the above into the Typescript playground, the error now is "Class 'BaseClass' defines instance member property 'dispose', but extended class 'MyClass' defines it as instance member function.". This means it's really easy to get around - not a reliable workaround for a 'sealed method'.

Comment: This is not a valid solution. If the child class also uses a lambda property TS will not complain. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=2#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgYVXQQG8AoBCpAewDtIoBXeKqACgEoSBfcygBwYhkAS1gIoOYABNayAJ4UpwsHypgcCALwIOALgQA3KsKlaAfCV6VKsWmCrIcAOmRUA5qwDkAEWWqwwjRuCHzAEjQQnuxWCDw8pChoGACycgRJCDgAHhA4NFIY2OrpRGTWAkKi4pIyNPIISipqGtp6hsammhZl1jZ2Ds6uHj5+aoHBsAAWwshSUTGxpFxAA

Comment: but then you can't create a `new A()`...so it's not really the same as `final` classes in other languages

Comment: This is AWESOME. Wish I could give you more than one upvote. :D It essentially substitutes for the lack of `virtual` and `override` as well.

Comment: You can still create an object of the class with a private constructor. The only thing you will need to do is create a public static wrapper method that calls the private constructor. `public static readonly create= () => new this();`

Answer (score -2):

```js
// I use this workaround:

export default class CreateHandler extends BaseHandler {
    // final prop used as method
    public readonly create = (blueprint: Blueprint): Response<Record> => {
        return blueprint.create();
    };

    // normal method
    public store(blueprint: Blueprint): Response<Record> {
        return this.response(blueprint.create());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of the code when posting an answer.