# Disabling componentWillMount() on child classes

Tags: reactjs, oop, typescript

I have the following structure.

```
abstract class AbstractComponent {
   public componentWillMount(): void {
     this.middlewares.forEach((middleware: MiddlewareInterface) => {
        return middleware.applyComponent(this).process();
     });
   }
}

class Component1 extends AbstractComponent  {
   protected middlewares: MiddlewareInterface[] = [
     PersonUpdateWillMount,
     PreventPageLeave
   ];

   // I DON'T WANT THIS TO BE POSSIBLE
   public componentWillMount() {

   }
}
```

Whenever I add `componentWillMount` to the main class, it overrides the functionality on abstract class.

Can I disable using `componentWillMount` somehow?

Comment: It seems that this is currently not possible. See the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814649/is-there-an-equivalent-to-sealed-or-final-in-typescript There is also an open issue for this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1534

Comment: @Michael Thanks alot. Does Javascript support reflections so I can have a look at the reflection of a class and throw an error manually?

Comment: Yes, you could somehow do this: if `let c1 = new Component1();` then `c1.constructor.prototype.hasOwnProperty("componentWillMount")` would return `true` if it overrides the method and `false` otherwise.

Comment: @Michael Perfect. I'll probably create my IOC and this is going to be something that IOC handles. Not sure what would be the performance impact but I assume this is going to be extremely low amount of overhead on object initialization.