# Is there a way to prevent type narrowing in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a way to prevent child class definitions overwriting the base class? Or prevent type narrowing? Either through compiler errors or linting warnings.

**Background**

I'm working on an Angular project that includes dozens of entities. Each entity maps to a SQL table but can also include extra custom properties before it reaches the client.

Right now I have two classes for each entity, a base class that is generated from SQL table column types, and the usable class which extends the base class and includes the custom properties.

The project is using --strictNullChecks

**The Issue**

The issue is that typescript allows for type narrowing, so if there's a property `Comments: string | null` on the base class, then the child class can have `Comments: string` without causing an error. But the actual value can be null so I don't want to accidentally narrow it and have the compiler think it's not nullable.

**Example**

```
// !!!DO NOT MODIFY!!! 
export abstract class CountryEntityBase {
    /** Max Length: 3 */
    Code: string;

    /** Max Length: 3 */
    Country_ID: string;

    /** Max Length: 50 */
    Description: string | null;

    IsActive: boolean;

    SortOrder: number | null;
}
```

```
export class CountryEntity extends CountryEntityBase {
    $id: string;
    $type: string;
    CreatedBy: string;
    CreatedDate: Date;
    Description: string; // I want to prevent this
}
```

Comment: TS doesn't want to prevent this because it's part of the way class extension works.  Not sure if there's a way to force it to do so, though.  Would [this](https://tsplay.dev/qWJx6N) work for you?

Comment: See [this answer on "Is there an equivalent to “sealed” or “final” in TypeScript?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43190973/3925507). Basically, no[t yet].

Comment: Or how do you feel about [private properties with get/set methods](https://tsplay.dev/jwg80N)?

Comment: @jcalz Because of the way we're parsing the entities they're just simple objects so we'd have to completely rewrite it for any getters/setters to actually exist at runtime. Your first suggesting might be the way we want to go. Just a little extra checking at compile time.

Comment: It sounds like your class is used to describe the properties of a parsed http response. If so, then you should not be using a class at all

Comment: @AluanHaddad Meaning we should be using Interfaces instead of classes? Because they are just being used to describe properties and provide no extra logic