# Making a method sealed in child class, so grandchildren cannot override it

Tags: typescript, oop, inheritance, javascript-objects, es6-class

There's an `abstract class A` that provides basic tools for a certain functionality. One of the children of class `A`, called `abstract class B` is a specific subset of the problem `A` is providing tools for, but with more restrictions.

So, I need to avoid children of `B` to override a certain method, while `B` itself overrides it from `A`, and other children of `A` can also override it.

Here's the thing I'm imagining in code:

```
abstract class A {
    public abstract foo();
    // ...
}

abstract class B extends A {
    public override foo() {
        // ...
    }
}

class CofB extends B {
    // This one shouldn't be able to override foo()
}

class XofA extends A {
    // But this one should still be able to override foo(), 
    // as it's extending A directly
}
```

In C# we can do this by marking `foo()` as `override sealed` in `B`.

But as TypeScript doesn't support this, what workarounds are there to achieve the same result? Or if there isn't any, how can I change the design to achieve the same thing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814649/is-there-an-equivalent-to-sealed-or-final-in-typescript

Comment: @AlekseyL. I saw that before posting this question. Unfortunately the workaround described in that thread [creating the method as a readonly variable in parent] doesn't seem to work in the case of sealing for 'grandchildren' (`A` allows overriding, but `B` seals it so `C` can't override it anymore).

Comment: Yeah, workaround doesn't work at all, but I'm afraid nothing new in this area..

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've settled with a run time check to ensure the method is not overridden.

This doesn't have the benefit of being safety checked at compile time, but *at least* this fails with a clear error message and avoids undefined behavior resulting in hard-to-debug bugs.

Here's what I did:

```
abstract class A {
    public abstract foo();
    // ...
}

abstract class B extends A {
    public override foo() {
        // ...
    }


    constructor() {
        super();
        
        if (this.foo !== B.prototype.foo) {
            throw new Error("Class is overriding foo, which is not allowed for children of B.");
        }
    }
}

class CofB extends B {
    
    // This compiles, but throws an error when trying to create an
    // instance of CofB; e.g. var x = new CofB();
    public override foo() {
        // ...
    }
}

class XofA extends A {

    // This works properly.
    public override foo() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Of course, having a way of implementing this in a way that results in compile time check would be much better; but so far I couldn't find one.