# Locking down a TypeScript class so that it is final and all invariants are guaranteed, even at runtime?

Tags: javascript, typescript, private, final, invariants

What is the best way of making a TypeScript class final, and ensure that all its invariants are guaranteed, even during runtime (when it might be accessed by arbitrary JavaScript code)?

A simple example of what I want to do is the following `MutableInt` class:

```js
export class MutableInt {

    static {
        Object.setPrototypeOf(MutableInt.prototype, null);
        Object.freeze(MutableInt.prototype);
        Object.freeze(MutableInt);
    }

    #value : number

    constructor (value : number = 0) {
        if (new.target !== MutableInt) throw new Error("MutableInt is final");
        if (!Number.isInteger(value)) throw new Error(`Integer expected, found: ${value}`);
        this.#value = value;
        Object.freeze(this);
    }

    get value(): number {
        return this.#value;
    }

    set value(v) {
        if (!Number.isInteger(v)) throw new Error(`Integer expected, found: ${v}`);
        this.#value = v;
    }

}
```

Is `MutableInt` properly locked down? Or is there something wrong or missing with this approach?

Edit: To clarify, I am not only interested in final decorators etc., I am interested in all sorts of ways `MutableInt` could be tampered with in a way such that it is not safe to use it. It seems in TypeScript / JavaScript there are a million attack vectors how an API can be compromised, and I am wondering if the above code considers all of them, or misses something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an equivalent to "sealed" or "final" in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814649/is-there-an-equivalent-to-sealed-or-final-in-typescript)

Comment: It is certainly related, but I am interested in all sorts of ways the integrity of MutableInt could be compromised. Also, I don't want to allow any subclasses at all.

Comment: I think you need to step-back and think about how TypeScript works and what the TypeScript language _really is_: Java and C# have `final` and `sealed` types because their respective runtime platforms are built around the concept of reusable `class` types exported from compiled binaries, whereas TypeScript is essentially just a transpiler to JavaScript, so there is **no point** in adding that functionality to TypeScript because it would only be a _pinkie-swear_ by `tsc` without any real runtime enforcement (which would be trivial to break), which TypeScript (by design) does not provide.

Comment: @Dai, that is why I am asking how to make sure that my class is secure even on a JavaScript runtime level. As to whether it would make sense to add this functionality to TypeScript: I think it would make a lot of sense. If you think my above protection of MutableInt can be trivially broken, how would you go about it?

Comment: I'm guessing you're _not_ familiar with [ES Modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) then? But even so, _what are you worried about_? If you're a library author you should be *encouraging* extension and use, not "locking down" - and if you're an application developer then you already "own" the final HTML+JS responses from the user-facing web-server, so you're always in control over what scripts do what, right down to the source level.

Comment: So do you have a way to break above protection or not? I am interested in offering a tamper prove API surface, for example for plugins that I loaded into my App.
As for how to extend an API, there are several ways to do it. Subclassing is not one I intend to support.

Comment: Apart from plugins, my app is not only going to use my module (in which MutableInt would reside), but also other libraries. I don't want these other libraries to be able to change the way my API works, even if in principle I can inspect the sources of these libraries.